# Custom fontsize for each pivotiem of a pivot

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, header, font-size, pivotitem

In my project of a Windows Phone 7 app, I use some Pivot, and I would like to know if it is possible to change the fontsize of the header of a pivotitem in c#.
For the moment, I know how to change all of the fontsize of the pivot. Here how I do it

```
<controls:Pivot x:Name="EventPivot">
    <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock x:Name="header" Text="Salut" FontSize="30" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
</controls:Pivot>
```

But my problem is that I didn't find how to change the Header text in c#. I tried

```
    TextBlock headerText = new TextBlock { Text = "toto", FontSize= 20, TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap};
    var myPivotItem = new PivotItem { Header = headerText};
    myPivotItem.Content = myScrollViewer;
    EventPivot.Items.Add(myPivotItem);
```

But that didn't work.
Maybe if I use some sort of DataTemplate as I did for the Pivot I could solve my problem but I don't know how to implement it in c#...

I wonder also if the height of the PivotItem could be independant from all other PivotItems. Because for the moment, the height of each header is based by the larger height of the others PivotItems.

Thanks for all of your answers.

Bye

Drhouse87

Answer (score 0):

Before implementing such a thing I'd test very carefully what the users think of such varying header item sizes. Not also that you'll likely have spacing issues as a result of this as the space reserved for the header will be applied to all pivot items.

That said, it should be possible to do this by binding a value to use for the FontSize and then applying a converter if need be.

You can't refer to items within a template by name from the code behind of the page as there could be multiple instances of the control wiht that name.